# check whether microsoft components are present or not

Tags: c#

I want to check whether certain microsoft components like wmencoder, directx or wmplayer
are installed or not. If it is installed, can I also get its version number?

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this for an install program? Or do you need to check for this in your C# program code?

Answer (score 3):

I use the below to determine if other applications are installed, however you will need to know the "unique" product code (from the setup project in Visual Studio) that the application is installed with in the registry.

Include

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Usage:

```
// HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} << This is outlook 2003
String retval = "";

// Look to see if Outlook 2003 is installed and if it is...
if ((checkComServerExists("{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", out retval)))
{
    // Update boolean flag if we get this far so we don't have to check again
    Console.WriteLine("Office CSLID exists - Version: " + retval);
}
```

Function:

```
// Checks to see if the given CLSID is registerd and exists on the system
private static Boolean checkComServerExists(String CLSID, out String retval)
{
    RegistryKey myRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    Object val;

    try
    {
        // get the pathname to the COM server DLL/EXE if the key exists
        myRegKey = myRegKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + CLSID + "\\LocalServer32");
        val = myRegKey.GetValue(null); // the null gets default
    }
    catch
    {
        retval = "CLSID not registered";
        return false;
    }

    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = null;
    try
    {
        // parse out the version number embedded in the resource
        // in the DLL
        myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(val.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        retval = String.Format("DLL {0} not found", val.ToString());
        return false;
    }

    retval = myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be WMI. Class Win32_SoftwareElement (on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394453(VS.85).aspx))

But likely to take some work to get the right classes and queries. Start with the WMI tools for WMI CIM Studio.

Using PowerShell, something like:

```
gwmi win32_softwareelement -filter "name like '%play%'" | ft
```

will allow finding the right ids. (Warning: this is *extremely* slow.)

Possible that the MS Installer (MSI) API has something quicker.

Comment: According to the question Tag, this seems like a C# question. Would you post a .NET (in C#) equivalent code for the PowerShell script?  Thanks.

Comment: That will take quite a bit of time (I don't often using WMI inside .NET code), and I likely don't have that time. The WQL to put into the System.management query class: SELECT * FROM Win32_SoftwareElement WHERE name like '%play%'.

Answer (score 0):

I use RegShot to determine registry setting that can be used to check if a softwre is installed ..

Answer (score 0):

[Here is also a small code snippet](http://pastebin.com/PvzCFsaT) that uses, among others, [`Type.GetTypeFromProgID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypefromprogid.aspx) and registry access.